# Protractor testing AngularJS fails to find an element by an id that does exist

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a sample AngularJS site @ https://gamersweb-js.firebaseapp.com/ with a protractor test case which is supposed to find an element by id on one of it's pages. The element with this id 'displayNameInHome' certainly does exist (in the user's 'Home' page), but the test case fails to find it there.

To get to the web page, log in using the credentials of user 'tester@qa.com' + password '123456', which will take you to the user's home page. The following test case fails to find element 'displayNameInHome' on this page, which will be the id of string 'tester' after the Welcome ....:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    //browser.get('http://localhost:5000/');
    browser.get('https://gamersweb-js.firebaseapp.com');
});

it('Testing display name in profile for logged in user:', function() {
element(by.model('loginUI.email')).clear().sendKeys('tester@qa.com');
element(by.model('loginUI.password')).clear().sendKeys('123456');
element(by.id('loginBtn')).click();

return browser.wait(function() {
    var displayNameInHome = element(by.id('displayNameInHome'));
    return displayNameInHome.getText().then(function(text) {
        return text =="tester";
    });
}, 10000);
```

});

I cannot figure out why the element 'displayNameInHome' is not found by the test case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, your reply was very helpful, correct, and a quick one too. The test case with your corrections now works. (the instructions here say to "avoid comments like 'thanks' ... ", so I didn't know what to do. I am new here) Thank you !

Comment: Done ... I was not aware initially I needed to do that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) is actually a condition to wait on. So your test is exiting pretty fast because the first parameter is not a condition.

Also, your test is lacking `expect`s.

I changed your code so that the test waits 10 seconds for the `#displayNameInHome` element to be present and then perform the assertion.

```
it('Testing display name in profile for logged in user:', function() {
    element(by.model('loginUI.email')).clear().sendKeys('tester@qa.com');
    element(by.model('loginUI.password')).clear().sendKeys('123456');
    element(by.id('loginBtn')).click();
    var displayNameInHome = element(by.id('displayNameInHome'));
    browser.wait(function() {
        return browser.isElementPresent(displayNameInHome)
    }, 10000);

    expect(displayNameInHome.getText()).toEqual('tester');
});
```